# Build OpenCV from source on Ubuntu 16.04, but failed to generate Java bindings

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to build OpenCV from source on Ubuntu to within a Java application, but when during processing `make` commanded, when it reaches to generate Java bindings it fails with the following error:

> [ 90%] Generate files for Java bindings Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/home/adil/Desktop/opencv/opencv/modules/java/generator/../generator/gen_java.py",
>   line 1093, in 
>       copy_java_files(java_files_dir, target_path)   File "/home/adil/Desktop/opencv/opencv/modules/java/generator/../generator/gen_java.py",
>   line 1042, in copy_java_files
>       package_path = 'org/opencv/' + module NameError: global name 'module' is not defined
>   modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/build.make:430:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dephelper/gen_opencv_java_source' failed
>   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dephelper/gen_opencv_java_source] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2799: recipe for target
>   'modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/all'
>   failed make[1]: ***
>   [modules/java_bindings_generator/CMakeFiles/gen_opencv_java_source.dir/all]
>   Error 2 Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
>   Error 2

I have installed every possible lib suggested on the Google and OpenCV website, nothing was solved the problem.

So what causes this error, and how solve?

**Note:** I have Java-9 installed on my machine.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ManuelTS It was the problem with Java generator in Python code, which has been solved in the latest release of OpenCV, you can download the latest source code from OpenCV Github, and try again.

Comment: @ManuelTS Or you can modify `modules/java/generator/gen_java.py` just change this line `re_package = re.compile(r'^package +(.+);$')` to this line `re_package = re.compile(r'^package +(.+);')`